# Como puedo crear un procedimiento que tome los valores de una columna especifica en un jtable y realice el insert en SQL

Tags: java, sql, jtable

Como puedo crear un procedimiento que tome los valores de una columna especifica en un jtable y realice el insert en SQL.

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
PreparedStatement insertar = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);)
{
    insertar.setInt(1,jComboNombreSalaEntrenamiento.getSelectedIndex());
    insertar.setInt(2,jComboNombreEntrenamiento.getSelectedIndex());
    insertar.setInt(3,jComboNombreDepartEnEntrenamientos.getSelectedIndex());
    insertar.setInt(4,jComboNombreEntrenadorEntrenamiento.getSelectedIndex());
    insertar.setString(5,Columna); //Este registro me deberia guardar todos los obtenidos en la columna del jtable
    insertar.setDate(6,FechaEntrenamiento);
 }
```

El insert obtiene los datos de cada combobox + los datos de una columna especifica del jtable, pero esa columna puede tener muchos registros, al ejecutar el insert este inserta solamente 1 registro (el primero que tiene la columna de mi tabla), pero se detiene ahí y no continua con los demas registros que siguen en la columna.
Como podria recorrer la tabla e igualar el insert a la cantidad de registros de la tabla? 
Ejemplo: 
Tabla = 20 registros.
Insertar 20 registros en mi base de datos...

Answer (score 0):

Hola te copio el codigo de como lo hice yo, lo saque de unos videos de youtube de geekepedia de ernesto.

```java
jTable_usuarios.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                int fila_point = jTable_usuarios.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int columna_point = 2;

                if(fila_point > -1){
                    user_update = (String)model.getValueAt(fila_point, columna_point);
                    InformacionUsuario informacion_usuario = new InformacionUsuario();
                    informacion_usuario.setVisible(true);
                }

            }
        });
```

Cuando hago click en la columna y fila seleccionada me abre otro formulario para que pueda editar esa fila de la tabla.

Ojala te sirva

Comment: Gracias amirgo, pero ya lo resolví de otra manera